# Invalid JSON response datatable using AJAX

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is my Json file:

```
{
"status":"success",
"offer_count":605,
"page":1,
"page_size":2000,
"offers":[ {
    "offer_id":1123125,
    "package_name":"",
    "name":"[PIN] DE Game of Thrones 3",
    "category":"mobile content",
    "description":"Flow: 3/4G: 2-click + PIN\r\nWIFI: MSISDN Input + PIN",

}
,
{
    "offer_id":1123543,
    "package_name":"",
    "name":"[PIN] DE iPhone X v2",
    "category":"mobile content",
    "description":"3/4G: 2-click + PIN\r\nWIFI: MSISDN Input + PIN",

}
}
```

### This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: "Bfrtip",

    ajax: {
        url: "myurl goes here",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "offers.name" },
        { data: "offers.offer_id" }

    ]

} );
} );
```

I am trying to populate the datatable using ajax but i am getting error of invalid JSON response. I have tried to check my json in chrome debugger but `the request has no response data available`. I am getting the data in console.log. How to populate the datatable with specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your JSON in an array.
you can google "json validator" and play with the file till it's correct json.

Comment: i dont have access to the json file as its on other server. I just have the URL

Comment: i just gave an example how the json file looks like. It is not full json file. I have checked it on json validator and it says valid json

Comment: Then you can treat it as plain text and with some string functions to extract the information you need

Comment: can you help me out a little bit in it

Comment: you need to share the function that have access to the data and how you trying to inject it to HTML

Answer (score 0):

change datatype to JSON  `dataType: 'json'` and you have an error in your JSON file please check  [ ]  { }

```
$.get('/path/to/file', function(data) {
   var my_json = data
},'json');
```

Comment: If i change to json datatype it will give cross domain error

Comment: please try this

$.get('/path/to/file', function(data) {
 var my_json = data
},'json');

Comment: I think you are sending data from backend is this incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialize according to showing an example and define column.

- Make sure you have return response from backend is correct according
  to DataTable

```js
 $('#datatable').DataTable({
                proccessing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                responsive: true,
                fixedHeader: {
                    header: true,
                    headerOffset: $('.header-navbar').outerHeight()
                },
                language: {
                    search: "",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
                },
                ajax: {
                    url: "Enter Url",
                    type: 'GET'
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: "Name", title: "Name" },
                    { data: "Email", title: "Email" },
                    {
                        data: "Message", title: "Message"
                    },
                ]
            });
```